# Change Border Color for DatePicker

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I would like to change the border color for the focus state on the `DatePicker` control.
I took a look at the Default Style Template and didn't see any Focus State for the `VisualStateManager`.

The only thing I saw was a primitive control for the `TextBox` as follows:

```
<controlsPrimitives:DatePickerTextBox x:Name="TextBox" SelectionBackground="{TemplateBinding SelectionBackground}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Column="0" />
```

How can I change the color for the focus state for the border for the `DatePicker`... I had no problem changing this color for the `TextBox`, `ComboBox` and the `CheckBox` controls.

Please Help!

Comment: Have you tried creating a template based on the DatePickerTextBox in Expression Blend?

Comment: I normally prefer to write the code myself, but Blend too useful to ignore when doing visual work in WPF or Silverlight.  I'd highly recommend investigating it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right, the `DatePicker` control doesn't have a Focus state for the `VisualStateManager`. Note that it *is* possible to add a state group and Focused/Unfocused states for the `DatePicker`, but that wouldn't be the best approach here.

The [template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278067%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for the `DatePicker` control contains a [`DatePickerTextBox` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.datepickertextbox%28VS.95%29.aspx), which, according to MSDN, "represents the text input of a `DatePicker`".

Looking at the template for the `DatePickerTextBox`, we find that it has a `FocusStates` state group, and definitions for both the `Unfocused` and `Focused` states. We also find this line:

```
<Border x:Name="FocusVisual" BorderBrush="#FF6DBDD1" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0"/>
```

So as you can see, the default "focused color" is [`#FF6DBDD1`](http://www.color-hex.com/color/6dbdd1). The `Focused` state for the `DatePickerTextBox` sets the `Opacity` property of this border to `1`.

To change the border color for the `Focused` state, you can create a copy of this template, replacing `#FF6DBDD1` with the color you want. Then, create a copy of the `DatePicker` template, which should specify that the `DatePickerTextBox` contained within it should use your modified template.

Alternatively, you can create a copy of the `DatePickerTextBox` template, make the adjustment to the border color, and place this template in a style with `TargetType` set to `DatePickerTextBox`:

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle1" TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
                <!-- Modified template for DatePickerTextBox goes here -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Hopefully this is useful to you!

---

**EDIT: Default Template for `DatePickerTextBox`**
Most of the default styles and templates for controls are available [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278075%28v=VS.95%29.aspx). However (for whatever reason), `DatePickerTextBox` is not. If you have a copy of Expression Blend (which I highly recommend if you are working with the appearance of controls; it's invaluable -- download a free trial [here](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc507094.aspx)), you can do the following:

Right-click on a `DatePicker`, click "Edit Template -> Edit a Copy...". You'll see the `DatePickerTextBox` in the "Objects and Timeline" panel. Right-click on that, click "Edit Template -> Edit a Copy..." once more. You can then right-click on the Template in the "Objects and Timeline" panel and click "View XAML."

Again, if you're doing any sort of work like this, I can't recommend Blend highly enough. It will save you so much time in the long run (and you'll learn a ton about XAML, styles, templates, how they all fit together, etc). If you don't have access to it, though, here's the default template for the `DatePickerTextBox` control:

```
<Style x:Key="DatePickerTextBoxStyle" TargetType="System_Windows_Controls_Primitives:DatePickerTextBox">
   <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="System_Windows_Controls_Primitives:DatePickerTextBox">
            <Grid x:Name="Root">
               <Grid.Resources>
                  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WatermarkBrush" Color="#FFAAAAAA"/>
               </Grid.Resources>
               <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                  <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                     <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="MouseOver"/>
                     </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                     <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                     <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                        <Storyboard>
                           <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                              <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF99C1E2"/>
                           </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                           <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement2">
                              <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF99C1E2"/>
                           </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                     </VisualState>
                  </VisualStateGroup>
                  <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WatermarkStates">
                     <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                     </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                     <VisualState x:Name="Unwatermarked"/>
                     <VisualState x:Name="Watermarked">
                        <Storyboard>
                           <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"/>
                           <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Watermark"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                     </VisualState>
                  </VisualStateGroup>
                  <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                     <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                     </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                     <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                     <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                        <Storyboard>
                           <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                     </VisualState>
                  </VisualStateGroup>
               </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
               <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="1" Opacity="1">
                  <Grid x:Name="WatermarkContent" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                     <Border x:Name="ContentElement" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                     <Border x:Name="ContentElement2" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1">
                        <ContentControl x:Name="Watermark" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Content="{TemplateBinding Watermark}" Foreground="{StaticResource WatermarkBrush}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" Opacity="0" Padding="2" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                     </Border>
                     <Border x:Name="FocusVisual" BorderBrush="#FF6DBDD1" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0"/>
                  </Grid>
               </Border>
            </Grid>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Apologies for the length, and many thanks to [this thread](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/163682/368531.aspx) (which had the same issue).

Comment: Just a small addition to an already good answer: if you don't want to copy over the whole DatePicker template, you can define a style with a TargetType set to DatePickerTextBox (with the right namespace prefix).

Comment: @Alex Good point, forgot about that. That's even simpler; will update my answer.

Comment: I was looking for the `DatePickerTextBox` template and could never find it... could you give me the link ?

Comment: @donut, that looks like the template for the `DatePicker` not the `DatePickerTextBox`, correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: @gmcalab Whoops, my mistake. Fixed, updated with the `DatePickerTextBox` style.

Comment: @Donut, thanks very much. This is exactly what I was looking for.... If MSDN would have supplied the template online like they do for `TextBox`, `ComboBox`, etc I would have done this a long time ago! But alas, I appreciate the insight on Blend, you deserve the bounty. Thanks! +110

Comment: @gmcalab No problem, I'm glad it was helpful. Just a friendly reminder: to award the bounty, you need to click the "+100" button to the left of the appropriate answer (it's separate from just marking an answer as accepted). Thanks! :)

Comment: @Donut, I will...it's still too early. I have a to wait another couple hours for it to allow me to give you the bounty. But I will definitely make sure it goes to you.

Comment: @gmcalab Haha ok thanks. I'm new to the bounty thing, never been awarded one before. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
public class MyDatePicker : DatePicker
{
    public MyDatePicker()
    { }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        DatePickerTextBox textBox = (DatePickerTextBox)this.GetTemplateChild("TextBox");
        textBox.GotFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(textBox_GotFocus);
        textBox.LostFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(textBox_LostFocus);
    }

    void textBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as DatePickerTextBox).BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }

    void textBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as DatePickerTextBox).ClearValue(DatePickerTextBox.BorderBrushProperty);
    }
}
```